# IIS 7.5 need to connect windows authentication to my active directory

Tags: active-directory, spring-security, iis-7.5, jboss7.x

I am using iis 7.5 and I need connect authentication to my spring app on jboss 7.1.1 via my active directory with the windows authenticated user.

It should check the windows user is valid in ad.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want following scenario:

- user pass authentication in windows
- when user opens web application then it will be authenticated automatically (**no need to type windows login / pasword twice**).

then Spring Security KERBEROS/SPNEGO extension is way to go. See [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/) blog entry for details.

If you want to have a login page (where your users can **retype their windows credentials**) then you can set up and use a special [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-active-directory) in your Spring Security config.